# Problems with the received data from NRF24L01

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am using NRF24L01 for wireless communication. My transmitter code is:

```
#include  <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"

//int msg[1];
RF24 radio(2,9); // CSN, CE
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;

void setup(){
        Serial.begin(9600);
        radio.begin();
        radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
        radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
        radio.stopListening();
        Serial.println("################## Set up complete ######################");
}

void loop(){
        const char data[] = "hello world!";
        radio.write(&data, sizeof(data));
        Serial.println("message sent");
        delay(1000);
}
```

My receiver code is:

```
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "SPI.h"

RF24 radio(8,7); // (CSN, CE)
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;

void setup(){
        Serial.begin(9600);
        radio.begin(); // Start the NRF24L01
        radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipe); // Get NRF24L01 ready to receive
        Serial.print("pipe open ... ");
        radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
        radio.startListening(); // Listen to see if information received
        Serial.println("Listening: ready to recieve ...");
}

void loop(){
        Serial.print("checking for radio signal ... ");
        if (radio.available()){
                Serial.print("| radio available | ");
                char data[32] = ""; // delcare data
                radio.read(&data, sizeof(data)); // read data from transmitter
                Serial.println(data);   // print data to serial
        }
        else {
                Serial.println("   Nothing");   // print if nothing read
        }
        delay(500);
}
```

when the transmitter sends its data, the receiver is supposed to print:

```
"checking for radio signal | radio available | "hello world!"
```

or when the transmitter sends no data, the receiver prints:

```
checking for radio signal | nothing
```

however, the receiver is printing:

```
b'checking for radio signal ...    Nothing\r\n'
b'checking for radio signal ...    Nothing\r\n'
b'checking for radio signal ... | radio available | \xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\x18\x03?\x01fpipe open ... \r\n'
b'checking for radio signal ... | radio available | \xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\x18\x03?\x01fpipe open ... \r\n'
b'checking for radio signal ...    Nothing\r\n'
b'checking for radio signal ...    Nothing\r\n'
```

Does anyone know why I am not seeing "hello world" and instead I am getting the odd strings of characters?

NOTE: I am also getting the same output even when the transmitter is off.

Comment: On an unrelated note: With `radio.write(&data, sizeof(data))`, which `&data` will work it's semantically wrong. You should pass a pointer to the first element (i.e. `&data[0]`) which is what plain `data` decays to. The difference between `&data` and `&data[0]` is the types: `&data` is of type `const char (*)[13]`, which `&data[0]` is of type `const char *`. The examples saying `&data` are wrong.

Comment: thanks for the input, I changed the line `radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));` into `radio.read(&data[0], sizeof(data[0]));` and now I get the output `b'checking for radio signal ... | radio available | \xff\r\n'`

Comment: Now you're giving the wrong type to the `sizeof` operator, as `data[0]` is a *single byte*. You need to pass the pointer to the first element (a pointer to `data[0]` , i.e. plain `data`) and then tell the size of the whole array (which is `sizeof data`).

Comment: thanks, so I'll try using `radio.read(&data[0], sizeof(data));`

Comment: Hi some programmer dude, I tried it and I still get `radio signal ... | radio available | \xff\r\n'`, I'm not sure where the \xff\xff\xff .... is coming from but then again I'm not even sure what `radio.available()` does, I assume it means that there is a signal

Comment: How are you expecting `Serial.printlen(data);` to know how many bytes to print?

Answer (score 0):

In the receive code, there is also a logical error. When you are straightaway printing "message sent" without any condition, it is executed every time irrespective of the message being sent or getting lost. Instead you should use

```c
if(radio.write(&data, sizeof(data))){
    Serial.println("Message Sent");
}else{
    Serial.println("Message not sent");
}
```

because radio.write returns TRUE if the data reached the receiver. else it returns FALSE, indicating the data has been lost.
Doing this you'll realize that the message is not being transmitted only.
Also CE is mentioned before CSN in RF24 radio(CE, CSN)